Projective transformation- Perspective with center $C$ on the line $r$

Suppose that the homography/projective transformation $f:P_{2}(\mathbb{R}) \to P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ that's not the identity, but it has a line $r$ of fixed points and doesn't fix any exterior point of $r$


Show that $f$ is a perspective with center $C$ on the line $r$, i.e., every point on the line $r$ is fixed and every line passing through $C$ is invariant.

Considering $P \notin r$ and $C=Pf(P) \cap r$, we should show
that $C$ is the center of $f$. Let $A,B \in r$ different than $C$, then considering $A,B,P,f(P)$, there isn't any three of them that are collinear and the same still holds for $A,B,f(P),f^{2}(P) (f(P) \in CP \implies f^{2}(P) \in Cf(P)=CP)$ and so there is an unique homography that maps $A,B,P,f(P)$ to $A,B,f(P),f^{2}(P)$ and considering $g$, a perspective of center $C$ on the line $r$ that maps $A,B,P,f(P)$ to $A,B,f(P),f^{2}(P)$, we must conclude that $f=g$. Is there something missing here? Any suggestions?
